# I am writing a poem and need to use the phrase "wrong from right" for the rhyme (...ight) Is "wrong from right" correct?

Tags: expressions

I am writing a poem and need to use the phrase "wrong from right" for the rhyme (...ight).  Is "wrong from right" correct rather than using (teaching children) "right from wrong"

Comment: _Right from wrong_ is more common than _wrong from right_, but both are grammatical. In any case, poets often bend or break the 'rules' of grammar to convey a particular effect or, as in your case, to create a rhyme.

Comment: How about the lyrics to Michael Jackson's *Black or White*? They print my message in the Saturday Sun
I had to tell them I ain't second to none
And I told about equality and it's true
*Either you're wrong or you're right*
But, if you're thinkin' about my baby
It don't matter if you're black or white

Comment: It worked for George Strait and Edmund Spencer.

Comment: It depends how you measure correctness. Using say 'span and spick' would be considered non-standard and either humorous, inventive, or ridiculous.

Comment: Consider the ending of the last musical number in the musical comedy _A Funny Thing Happened on the Way to the Forum_. It goes "What is the moral?/Must be a moral./Here is the moral, wrong or right:/Moral tomorrow, Comedy tonight!" If that works, as it surely does, than _wrong from right_ does, too.

Comment: If Lord Byron could say *"through thin and thick"* for the rhyme, surely you can say *"wrong from right"*.

Answer (score 2):

The order of the words in your phrasing is not as common as its reverse, however it's still perfectly understood and grammatical.

That aside, it would also be quite acceptable on the grounds of [poetic license](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/poetic_licence):

> The freedom to depart from the facts of a matter or from the conventional rules of language when speaking or writing in order to create an effect.

So long as it appears deliberate, rather than a mistake, it's fine.

---

This is not directly relevant to my answer, but I couldn't help but be reminded of it.

["In Love, His Grammar Grew,"](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poetrymagazine/poems/55220/in-love-his-grammar-grew) by Stephen Dunn:

> In love, his grammar grew
> rich with intensifiers, and adverbs fell
> madly from the sky like pheasants
> for the peasantry, and he, as sated
> as they were, lolled under shade trees
> until roused by moonlight
> and the beautiful fraternal twins
> *and* and *but*. Oh that was when
> he knew he couldn’t resist
> a conjunction of any kind.
> One said *accumulate*, the other
> was a doubter who loved the wind
> and the mind that cleans up after it.
>
> For love
> he wanted to break all the rules,
> light a candle behind a sentence
> named Sheila, always running on
> and wishing to be stopped
> by the hard button of a period.
> Sometimes, in desperation, he’d look
> toward a mannequin or a window dresser
> with a penchant for parsing.
> But mostly he wanted you, Sheila,
> and the adjectives that could precede
> and change you: *bluesy*, *fly-by-night*,
> *queen of all that is and might be*.